# Standard score applied to data that is not normally distributed

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, standardization, z-score, feature-scaling

If I scale data from an arbitrary distribution using the standard score, will the property of the normal distribution that 75% of data lies between +/- 2 standard deviations from the mean, still hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.75 does not even apply to the normal distribution.  But to your question, linear scaling does not fix non-normality so the answer is no.  And scaling/standardizing by the standard deviation can be a bad idea, as SD mainly applies to symmetric distributions that are not too heavy-tailed.

Comment: true, the 75% within two standard deviations are by chebyshev inequality